# When and how is a sqlalchemy link table object created?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I have a many to many relation in sqlalchemy and that link table is mapped to a class, how and when is that ORM object created? I'm not able to find it through the session.new for example.

Here is a minimal example to explain it:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, String, Integer, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()


class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    employees = relationship(
        'Employee',
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    departments = relationship(
        Department,
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )


class DepartmentEmployeeLink(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department_employee_link'
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'), primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


session = Session()
department = Department(name='department')
employee = Employee(name='employee')
department.employees.append(employee)
session.add(department)

# When does DepartmentEmployeeLink get created if ever as an ORM object?
print session.new
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No instance of `DepartmentEmployeeLink` is created unless you explicitly query that table. For inserting and querying `Employee` or `Department` instances the information in the `DepartmentEmployeeLink` *class* object is sufficient. There is no need create instances for that.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that is the expected behaviour then.

If that object is never created, how can I inspect the session before committing and also include changes like that? Since looking at new for example is not enough.